# Table View presented modally has no navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, ios6

When I present a view controller modally:

> // Display the nav controller modally.
>
> [self presentModalViewController:theNavController animated:YES];

The navigation bar is covered up the view the pops up!
How can I get the navigation bar to not get covered up??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Position the view that is covering it below the navigation bar.  It covers it because the views share the same superview and probably both have a y-origin of 0.

Comment: Either add a navigationBar or wrap the presented controller in a `UINavigationController`

Comment: Can you explain with code? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers can be found at [iPhone: Show modal UITableViewController with Navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600448/iphone-show-modal-uitableviewcontroller-with-navigation-bar)
and
[UINavigationBar refuses to show in Modal View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690917/uinavigationbar-refuses-to-show-in-modal-view-controller)!

You need to wrap the `UIViewController` in a `UINavigationController`, and then present the navigation controller:

```
AccountViewController* accountViewController = [[AccountViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AccountView" bundle:nil]; 
... 
// Initialize properties of accountViewController 
... 
UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:accountViewController]; 
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES]; 
[navController release]; 
[accountViewController release];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewContorller:someViewController];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```